# Reassigning values in list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I was solving Kaggle list & comprehensions module and got the wrong answer for the following code:

```
def elementwise_greater_than(L, thresh):
    """Return a list with the same length as L, where the value at index i is 
    True if L[i] is greater than thresh, and False otherwise.
    
    >>> elementwise_greater_than([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
    [False, False, True, True]
    """
    for num in L:
        if L[num] > thresh:
            L[num] = True
        else:
            L[num] = False
    return L
    pass
```

It gives the following output: `[False, False, 3, True]`

There's a mistake in `if L[num]>thresh` but I can't understand what is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python the in operator iterates over the values not the keys(as opposed to javascript) so L[num] will give you nonsense values.

try getting the length and using a regular for

```py
def elementwise_greater_than(L, thresh):
    """Return a list with the same length as L, where the value at index i is 
    True if L[i] is greater than thresh, and False otherwise.
    
    >>> elementwise_greater_than([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
    [False, False, True, True]
    """
    count = len(L)
    for num in range(0,count):
        if L[num] > thresh:
            L[num] = True
        else:
            L[num] = False
    return L
```

Comment: thanks for **in** explanation. Now I get why the answer was weird

Answer (score 1):

First thing don't write on the input L, create a different list.
secondly when looping like this:

```
for num in L:
```

num is the value and not the index in each position.

Here is the code:

```
def elementwise_greater_than(L, thresh):
    """Return a list with the same length as L, where the value at index i is 
    True if L[i] is greater than thresh, and False otherwise.
    
    >>> elementwise_greater_than([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
    [False, False, True, True]
    """
    lst = []
    for num in L:
        if num > thresh:
            lst.append(True)
        else:
            lst.append(False)
    return lst
```

And output:

```
[False, False, True, True]
```

Comment: why it's working with empty list and not the filled one? Just curious about technology here

Comment: it will work on the filled list but its not a good practice to override the input instead its better to create an empty list and fill it.